# "Don't be such a Phoebe." (The Simpsons)

Tags: meaning-in-context

A conversation between two young schoolgirls. From *The Simpson's* 10th season.

> – Is that perfume?
>
> – Oh! Don't be such a *Phoebe*.

What does it mean to *be a Phoebe*? Does *Phoebe* refer to a bird or the character from *Friends*?

Comment: I don't know if this is really a question about English, but according to [SNPP](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/5F20), the character who said the line was voiced by Lisa Kudrow, who also played Phoebe on Friends.  (I'd have no idea what "don't be such a Phoebe" meant without looking it up on Google.)

Comment: No idea. Phoebe is a girl's name. Do you think you heard it correctly? Could it be another word such as "dweeb"?

Comment: I agree with snailplane. I don't think most people would get this reference outside the context of this particular _Simpsons_ episode. (Of course, there's no way for the O.P. to know this; it's a fair question.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed a reference to Lisa Kudrow's character on Friends.

Phoebe is pretty much a [hippie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippie) or at least [granola](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=granola), and would never buy or apply something so unnatural as perfume.

Lisa Kudrow's character is telling Lisa Simpson to lighten up and embrace all things trendy and feminine in a way that gives a nod to Kudrow's most famous role (and supplies an in-joke/confirmation for all the viewers who had by this point identified her by her distinctive voice).

Comment: It's worth noting that _The Simpsons_ is well-known for its multilayer humor, often peppered with inside jokes. The show also features [several famous guest stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Simpsons_guest_stars), some of whom refer to themselves in subtle ways. One of my favorite lines is when Homer goes to Rock-and-Roll camp; when camp is over, Mick Jagger (playing himself) tells a disappointed Homer to cheer up, "it's only rock and roll camp", and Homer responds, "but I like it." That star-studded episode also featured Keith Richards, Tom Petty, Elvis Costello & Lenny Kravitz.

Answer (score 4):

This line refers to the show "Friends" which guest star Lisa Kudrow also stared in as Phoebe.

It probably means "Don't be so stupid or naive" (two characteristics of Phoebe)

Comment: I just made a couple minor edits to this post. You might want to take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/996) to avoid making that same error.